# Angular how to include $http when minifying JS

Tags: angularjs

Since I'm minifying and uglifying my JS, I can't simply do the following:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {
// ...
});
```

It will throw an inject-related error since minifying it jumbles up the $scope var.

Instead, I have to do this:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.angularIs = "awesome";
}]);
```

Question: Using the second approach, how do I add the http service? Something like this?

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope&$http', function($scope, $http) {
// ...
}]);
```

And can my `angular.module('app', []);` declaration stay the same, or do I have to add some type of http dependency to the `[]`'s? Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: btw, using a build tool like gulp/grunt you can automagically add these so you don't have to "double inject" everywhere. https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ng-annotate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  // ...
}]);
```

It will match then against the arguments inside function(). Your app's dependencies will always be strings, so those will be fine when minified.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
// ...
}]);
```